# jsoup getting specific tags and values relating to them

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I am new to jsoup and want to get more familiar on how to extract information from websites. I am trying to do something simple: getting some values from eBay.

I want to get item name, html link, price and amount sold from "hot this week" (like here: http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/Action-Figures/246/bn_1632128/i.html)

However I am unsure of how to proceed.

```
package application;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class GetHotSellers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc =  Jsoup.parse(readURL("http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/Action-Figures/246/bn_1632128/i.html"));

        Elements sold_items = doc.getElementsMatchingText("sold$");   
        for(Element sold : sold_items) {
                System.out.println(sold.text());
        }
    }


     public static String readURL(String url) {

     String fileContents = "";
     String currentLine = "";

     try {
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream()));
         fileContents = reader.readLine();
         while (currentLine != null) {
             currentLine = reader.readLine();
             fileContents += "\n" + currentLine;
         }
         reader.close();
         reader = null;
     } catch (Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error Message", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
         e.printStackTrace();

     }

     return fileContents;
    }

}
```

This is as far as I got. Do I need to improve my regex or do I need to use some other function more suitable for my request?

My current output looks like this:

```
2016 8PC Marvel Avengers DC Super Hero Mini Figure Set Fits Lego FROM UK Â£6.35 381 sold Despicable Me Minions Supervillain Jet Playset -From the Argos Shop on ebay Â£7.99 187 sold Avengers Marvel Titan 12" figure Spider-man Captain Iron man Wolverine Thor Toy Â£8.69 174 sold Imaginext Marvel DC Super Hero Squad Figures and Villains Batman Please select Â£1.99 129 sold Star Wars Episode The Force Awakens Electronic Chewbacca Mask IN STOCK NOW! Â£24.99 101 sold Jurassic World Indominus Rex Chomping Dinosaur 44cm Figure T-Rex Dino Action Toy Â£26.99 89 sold 12" Avengers Marvel Titan Figures Spider-Man Captain Iron Man Wolverine Thor Toy Â£7.45 88 sold Henry Hugglemonster Huggle House Playset. From the Official Argos Shop on ebay Â£7.99 87 sold
2016 8PC Marvel Avengers DC Super Hero Mini Figure Set Fits Lego FROM UK Â£6.35 381 sold Despicable Me Minions Supervillain Jet Playset -From the Argos Shop on ebay Â£7.99 187 sold Avengers Marvel Titan 12" figure Spider-man Captain Iron man Wolverine Thor Toy Â£8.69 174 sold Imaginext Marvel DC Super Hero Squad Figures and Villains Batman Please select Â£1.99 129 sold Star Wars Episode The Force Awakens Electronic Chewbacca Mask IN STOCK NOW! Â£24.99 101 sold Jurassic World Indominus Rex Chomping Dinosaur 44cm Figure T-Rex Dino Action Toy Â£26.99 89 sold 12" Avengers Marvel Titan Figures Spider-Man Captain Iron Man Wolverine Thor Toy Â£7.45 88 sold Henry Hugglemonster Huggle House Playset. From the Official Argos Shop on ebay Â£7.99 87 sold
2016 8PC Marvel Avengers DC Super Hero Mini Figure Set Fits Lego FROM UK Â£6.35 381 sold
2016 8PC Marvel Avengers DC Super Hero Mini Figure Set Fits Lego FROM UK Â£6.35 381 sold
2016 8PC Marvel Avengers DC Super Hero Mini Figure Set Fits Lego FROM UK Â£6.35 381 sold
381 sold
381 sold
Despicable Me Minions Supervillain Jet Playset -From the Argos Shop on ebay Â£7.99 187 sold
Despicable Me Minions Supervillain Jet Playset -From the Argos Shop on ebay Â£7.99 187 sold
Despicable Me Minions Supervillain Jet Playset -From the Argos Shop on ebay Â£7.99 187 sold
187 sold
187 sold
Avengers Marvel Titan 12" figure Spider-man Captain Iron man Wolverine Thor Toy Â£8.69 174 sold
Avengers Marvel Titan 12" figure Spider-man Captain Iron man Wolverine Thor Toy Â£8.69 174 sold
Avengers Marvel Titan 12" figure Spider-man Captain Iron man Wolverine Thor Toy Â£8.69 174 sold
174 sold
174 sold
Imaginext Marvel DC Super Hero Squad Figures and Villains Batman Please select Â£1.99 129 sold
Imaginext Marvel DC Super Hero Squad Figures and Villains Batman Please select Â£1.99 129 sold
Imaginext Marvel DC Super Hero Squad Figures and Villains Batman Please select Â£1.99 129 sold
129 sold
129 sold
Star Wars Episode The Force Awakens Electronic Chewbacca Mask IN STOCK NOW! Â£24.99 101 sold
Star Wars Episode The Force Awakens Electronic Chewbacca Mask IN STOCK NOW! Â£24.99 101 sold
Star Wars Episode The Force Awakens Electronic Chewbacca Mask IN STOCK NOW! Â£24.99 101 sold
101 sold
101 sold
Jurassic World Indominus Rex Chomping Dinosaur 44cm Figure T-Rex Dino Action Toy Â£26.99 89 sold
Jurassic World Indominus Rex Chomping Dinosaur 44cm Figure T-Rex Dino Action Toy Â£26.99 89 sold
Jurassic World Indominus Rex Chomping Dinosaur 44cm Figure T-Rex Dino Action Toy Â£26.99 89 sold
89 sold
89 sold
12" Avengers Marvel Titan Figures Spider-Man Captain Iron Man Wolverine Thor Toy Â£7.45 88 sold
12" Avengers Marvel Titan Figures Spider-Man Captain Iron Man Wolverine Thor Toy Â£7.45 88 sold
12" Avengers Marvel Titan Figures Spider-Man Captain Iron Man Wolverine Thor Toy Â£7.45 88 sold
88 sold
88 sold
Henry Hugglemonster Huggle House Playset. From the Official Argos Shop on ebay Â£7.99 87 sold
Henry Hugglemonster Huggle House Playset. From the Official Argos Shop on ebay Â£7.99 87 sold
Henry Hugglemonster Huggle House Playset. From the Official Argos Shop on ebay Â£7.99 87 sold
87 sold
87 sold
```

And my wanted output example:

```
Henry Hugglemonster Huggle House Playset. From the Official Argos Shop on ebay || £7.99 || 87 sold || http://link.com
```

Edit:

Just tried something like this, but no luck.

```
for(String categoryURL : categoryLinksArray) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(readURL(categoryURL));
    Elements sold_items = doc.getElementsByClass("b-block-info-container");
    for(Element sold : sold_items) {
            System.out.println("NAME: " + sold.attr("b-block-info-container__title b-block-info-container__title__ListingSummary") + "\n" + 
                               "PRICE: " + sold.attr("b-block-info-container__price") + "\n" +
                               "SOLD/week: " + sold.attr("item_quantity__hotness") + "\n" +
                               "URL: " + sold.attr("abs:href"));
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it but not very efficiently as it's very slow.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> categoryLinksArray = new ArrayList<>();

    Document links = Jsoup.parse(readURL("http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/allcategories/all-categories"));
    Elements item_categories = links.getElementsByClass("ch");
    for (Element category : item_categories) {
        categoryLinksArray.add(category.attr("abs:href"));
    }

    for (String categoryURL : categoryLinksArray) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(readURL(categoryURL));
        Elements hot_items = doc
                .getElementsByClass("b-module b-module-carousel b-module-deals topSold b-display--portrait");
        for (Element item : hot_items) {

            Elements hot_items_names = item.getElementsByClass(
                    "b-block-info-container__title b-block-info-container__title__ListingSummary");
            Elements hot_items_price = item.getElementsByClass("b-block-info-container__price");
            Elements hot_items_sold = item.getElementsByClass("item_quantity__hotness");
            Elements hot_items_url = item.getElementsByClass("b-block-tile");

            HashMap<String, String> hs_items = new HashMap<>();

            for (Element item_name : hot_items_names) {
                hs_items.put("Name", item_name.text());
            }
            for (Element item_price : hot_items_price) {
                hs_items.put("Price", item_price.text());
            }
            for (Element item_sold : hot_items_sold) {
                hs_items.put("Sold", item_sold.text());
            }
            for (Element item_url : hot_items_url) {
                hs_items.put("URL", item_url.attr("abs:href"));
            }

            System.out.println("Name: " + hs_items.get("Name") + "\n" +
                               "Price: " + hs_items.get("Price") + "\n" +
                               "Sold: " + hs_items.get("Sold") + "\n" +
                               "URL: " + hs_items.get("URL") + "\n" +
                               "----------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupTest {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {            
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/Action-Figures/246/bn_1632128/i.html").get(); //connect to url and get the document
        Element hotThisWeek = doc.getElementById("w6-2-x-carousel-items"); // select the div by its ID // better than matching text because id is unique
        Elements items = hotThisWeek.select("li");    // select all li tags        
        for(Element e : items){
            System.out.println(  e.select("div.b-block-info-container__title").text() // select the div with title text by class name
                     + " || " +  e.select("div.b-block-info-container__price").text()  // select the price-div by its class name
                     + " || " +  e.select("div.item_quantity__hotness").text()  // select hotness-div by class name 
                     + " || " +  e.select("a").attr("href")); //select a tag and get value of attribute href 
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this with all categories but get NullPointer at Jsoup.connect line. Do you think It's because `"w6-2-x-carousel-items"` is unique to the toys category?

Comment: Yes the id is unique. So that would not work for the rest of the page. But if you inspect the html code of the page you will see some kind of structure. See my second answer and modify it where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The page is organised in sections. Those section tags have each an Id starting by id="w2", id="w3" ... till id="w10". You can use this to go over each section and pick the data you are interessted in. Example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupTest {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/Action-Figures/246/bn_1632128/i.html").get();
        for(int i = 2; i<11;i++){
            Element category = doc.getElementById("w"+i); // select section with id = w2 , w3, w4 ...
            if(!category.select("div.b-module-carousel__title").isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(category.select("div.b-module-carousel__title").text()); // the title of the section is either here
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(category.select("div.b-block-list__header").text());  // or here
            }
            Elements items = category.select("li");            
            for(Element e : items){
                System.out.println(  e.select("div.b-block-info-container__title").text() 
                        // to get prices or trending-prices
                        // (some boolean expression which can be true or false)?return this if true:return this part if false
                         + " || " +  ((!e.select("div.b-block-info-container__price").isEmpty())?e.select("div.b-block-info-container__price").text():(e.select("div.b-block-info-container__trending-prices-group").text()))
                         + " || " +  e.select("div.item_quantity__hotness").text()
                         + " || " +  e.select("a").attr("href"));
            }
            System.out.println("************************************************************************************"); // just added to separate the categories
        }            
    } 
}
```